# Кракозябры в базе и вопросики на сайте

Tags: php, mysql, кодировка, utf-8

Уважаемые профессионалы, перепробовав множество вариантов с форумов и гугла запутался окончательно, поэтому вынужден просить помощи.
Кодировка файлов у меня - utf-8, в базе вроде тоже такая же кодировка, но что бы
я ни делал всегда натыкаюсь на два варианта результата - либо на сайте отображается норм, а в базе кракозябры, либо в базе норм, а на сайте вопросики вместо кириллицы
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Посмотрел в базе, там:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При создании полей везде указал utf8_general_ci. Никак не могу понять в чем проблема. В meta везде charset=utf-8.
Попробовал получить кодировку сервера через character_set_name() - выдает latin1.  Подскажите пожалуйста, запутался уже совсем

Comment: Создайте пустой html файл с кириллицей и откройте в браузере. Скорее всего у вас неправильная кодировка сервера, у вас только nginx, или апач еще проксируется?

Comment: @ВадимАлександру можете объяснить, какое отношение  html, nginx или апач имеют к **кодировке базы данных**?

Comment: @Ипатьев По вашему он вручную вводит данные в базу? Html никакое не имеет, но так мы можем удостовериться, что кодировка самого nginx правильная и нужно копать на сторону php.  Судя по скринам в базе кодировка верная, но в нее приходят данные в другой кодировке.

Comment: @Ипатьев Есть такая пословие, критикуешь - предлагай. У вас пока что только первое распирает

Comment: @ВадимАлександру это просто потому нормально ответить тупо занимает больше времени, чем просто ткнуть пальцем в небо :)

Comment: @Ипатьев по вашему автор дал достаточно информации для полноценного ответа?

Comment: @ВадимАлександру на удивиление - да. Второй скриншот - из phpmyadmin, который конечно чудовищная программа  и погибель разработчика, но с кодировками работать умеет. то есть первые две строки БД приняла однобайтные, и записала как есть.

Answer (score 0):

База испорчена, в ней есть строки в двух кодировках.
Строка с id 3 в нормальной utf, а 1 и 2 - в какой-то однобайтной кодировке. Судя по всему, третья вводилась в phpmyadmin, а первые две - на сайте.

Чтобы на сайте данные нормально вводились и отображались данные

- выкинуть на помойку бессмысленное "meta везде charset=utf-8", которое ни на что не влияет
- научиться [нормально соединяться с БД](https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli/mysqli_connect), в частности сообщать базе данных, **в какой кодировке** данные приходят с сайта.